# Salesforce geolocation pincode match

Tags: google-maps, salesforce, geocoding

I have a requirement in Salesforce where i have to enter a pincode and it should display the nearest matches and also a google map with the locations pinned on it through markers . Can anyone help me out with this ? Code or guidance or anything is appreciated .  THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Map API, Full tutorial on below link. you can capture by latitude and longitude is good idea.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

I did this in below link

[Search by zipcode to pin in ajax scroll](http://newlineinfo.com/websites/regionsimaging)